# Autolayout different in Simulator and Device

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, ios-simulator

I´m construction a UITableViewCells with autolayout. It works as expected in the simulator without auto layout errors or warnings.

Running the app on a device (same type as simulator) shows the following log message and the layout is not as expected.

```
2017-10-31 18:59:02.724396+0100 StaticTableTest01[8239:4373602] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170099050 V:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x100e0bb90'row 0 sec: 0']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x100e06e40 )>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170099230 UITextField:0x100f083b0.top == UILabel:0x100e0bb90'row 0 sec: 0'.top   (active)>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170099320 UITextField:0x100f083b0.height == 41   (active)>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700993c0 UITextField:0x100f083b0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x100e06e40.bottom - 10   (active)>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093920 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x100e06e40.height == 43.5   (active)>"
)
```

What can be the reason for this difference ?

That´s the code for the UITableViewCell

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let lb1 = UILabel()
lb1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
lb1.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
lb1.numberOfLines = 0

if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
{ lb1.text = "r\(indexPath.row)c:\(indexPath.section) very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text"
} else
{ lb1.text = "row \(indexPath.row) sec: \(indexPath.section)"
}


let tf1 = UITextField()
tf1.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
tf1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

cell.contentView.addSubview(lb1)
cell.contentView.addSubview(tf1)

let second = lb1.superview

NSLayoutConstraint(item: lb1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: second, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: lb1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: second, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: lb1, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:nil , attribute: .notAnAttribute , multiplier: 1, constant: 250).isActive = true

tf1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lb1.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
tf1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (second?.trailingAnchor)!, constant: -10).isActive = true
tf1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lb1.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

let labelHeight = lb1.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:250, height:1000), limitedToNumberOfLines: 4).size.height
let textFieldHeight = tf1.intrinsicContentSize.height

tf1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: textfHeight).isActive = true

if labelHeight >= textfHeight
{ NSLayoutConstraint(item: lb1, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: second, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10).isActive = true
} else
{ NSLayoutConstraint(item: tf1, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: second, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

[image: Screenshot Simulator]
[image: Screenshot Device]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of your layout?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. There are no real-life situations in which you would ever say `let cell = UITableViewCell()`. If you're doing this in connection with a UITableView, you're using the table view incorrectly. If you're doing it outside of any table view, you have no business using a table view cell. You need to think (and explain) more about what you are really trying to do. Your entire interface architecture is at fault; the auto layout issue is merely diagnostic of the larger issue.

Comment: I want to construct a static UITableView programaticly. How else can I construct the rows of such a static UITableView?

Comment: You should reuse your cells with `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:))`

Comment: @lufritz I want to create the rows of a static UITableView programaticly. Isn´t tableView.dequeueReusableCell made for IB desiged cells?

Comment: @mica - you want to *dynamically* create *static* cells? That is rather confusing. Anything you "create via code" is, pretty much by definition, **not** static. Your images show 4 cells, and they all look the same (except for row 0 section 1 having multiple lines). Will you have any other cells? or cells that will have other elements? and you are using text fields because they will be editable?

Comment: @DonMag I used the term "static" in analogy the the "static" UITableViews in IB where you design every cell as needed. What I want to do in the end is using a UITableView for showing a screen with rows containing a label and  few controls to input data (a bit like the settings app). The construction shall be done in code not in IB.

Comment: @mica - are you *sure* you used the same Simulator configuration as your actual device? I get the same constraint failure on iPhone 7+ Simulator **and** device, but I do **not** get it on iPhone 7. Regardless, take a look at my answer. A tip for the future though... If you are asking for help, post your actual code - or at least an actual sample that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted would not run as-is (`textfHeight` unresolved), and you do not show color settings or textField text. So we have to do some guessing to try and help.

Comment: "Isn´t tableView.dequeueReusableCell made for IB desiged cells?" No, the method was made for memory management purposes to intelligently reuse cells as they appear/disappear from the screen, regardless if they were designed in code or IB.

Comment: @BergQuester Thanks! Then the UITableViewCell classes have to be registered before, right? Do you think it´s a big win, if you have ca 10-20 different UITableViewCell classes. Each row its own class.

Comment: @mica - In a previous comment you mention "What I want to do in the end is using a UITableView for showing a screen with rows containing a label and few controls to input data (a bit like the settings app)" Unless you have a particular need to use a table view, I would probably go about this by either laying this all out in a single large UIView and using a UIScrollView or using a CocoaPod such as SwiftySettings to handle the layout for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line where you are setting the Height constraint on your text field:

```
let labelHeight = lb1.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:250, height:1000), limitedToNumberOfLines: 4).size.height
let textFieldHeight = tf1.intrinsicContentSize.height

// delete this line
//tf1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: textFieldHeight).isActive = true

if labelHeight >= textFieldHeight
{ NSLayoutConstraint(item: lb1, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: second, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10).isActive = true
} else
{ NSLayoutConstraint(item: tf1, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: second, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

Since you are *asking for* the `.intrinsicContentSize.height`, it doesn't make much sense to then try to **set** the height.

Comment: Thanks. Right, the tf1.height Constraint is not needed. After deleting it still works in the simulator and not on the device. I don´t get the constraint Error on 7+ simulator also. - hmm!

Comment: Constructing the tableview I had set the estimatedRowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. After changing that to 100 the simulator and the device behave similar, except that on the device the table start on the very top of the screen (covering the "status" line with carrier, signal, batterie etc.), see the screenshots in the Question
    tableView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

Comment: I think it´s because of the simulator running iOS11 and the device iOS10

Comment: *"... UITableViewAutomaticDimension. After changing that to 100 ..."* and *"iOS 11 / iOS 10"* -- that's part of what I meant in my comments to your question: If you only show the part of the code you *think* matters, then we very possibly are missing the part that ***does*** matter. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you are right. somtimes its not easy to find the right balance between minimal and complete ;-) Thnx for your help!